# How can I use Wismote in Contiki-NG?

Tags: contiki, contiki-ng

I am running Cooja and Contiki-NG using Docker. When I want to emulate a simple application using "Wismote" mote, Cooja returns the following error:

```
> make udp-server.wismote TARGET=wismote 
../../Makefile.include:100: *** The target platform "wismote" does not exist (maybe it was misspelled?).  Stop.
Process returned error code 2
```

The application works properly with Z1 and Sky motes.  Does anyone know how I can add Wismote to Contiki-NG and emulate a program using it?

Thank you!